# How can I use CORS POST in RequireJS?

Tags: requirejs, cors

I have used jQuery to send the same "CORS POST" to **this url** so the server side should have no problem.
But I'm writing another html page without jQuery. As a result, now I want to realise the same CORS POST, using some other utility.
Will RequireJS, which is already used in my current page, be able to do this?

I find some documents saying that it can automatically switch to JSONP when needed. But it's **get** not **post**, and I hope I won't need to realise CORS and JSONP at the same time on server side.

Comment: without jQuery. Arent you using some other framework to ease your job, or you are writing all by yourself. xmlhttprequest?

Comment: @Vishwanath I also use AngularJS. And I'm using AngularJS to do this now. I just want to know if this thing can be achieved by RequireJS.

Comment: Check angularjs [http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service.

Comment: @Vishwanath Well, thank you if it means CORS POST using Require is not needed or supported. :D

Comment: Purpose of requirejs is async download and dependency management of your assets. Using it to get json files or jsonp service is added functionality which doesnt deflect it from its purpose. Doing post request is completely out of the scope of the requirejs.

Comment: @Vishwanath Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vishwanath has told me that cors post is out of the range of RequireJS in comments.
I need to close this question.